# D3 Javascript / SVG Part III ISsue

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm following the part III tutorial of "Let' Make Some Charts" as an introduction to D3. Part of the tutorial calls for data insertion via TSV. Given I don't see this being an eventual use case for me, I'm attempting to modify the tutorial with the code below using a simple javascript array. However, nothing shows up on the page when I render in the browser. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Here's the tutorial link for some reference to the original code: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/

My JS code:

```
        <script>
        var data = [4,8,15,16,23,42,57,89,100,160];

        var width = 960,
            height = 500; // have to make sure variables are case sensitive

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data)]) // scaling based on max value
            .range([height, 0]);

        var chart = d3.select(".chart")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        var barWidth = width / data.length;

        var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
                    .data(data)
                .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)";});

        bar.append("rect")
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
            .attr("width", barWidth - 1)
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });   

        bar.append("text")
            .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value) + 3; })
            .attr("dy", ".75em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

        function type(d) {
            d.value = +d.value;
            return d;
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: what's in the console?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've copied references a named attribute `value` to determine what to draw. The data you've created doesn't have this but just the data. So everywhere you have `d.value`, you need to reference just `d`.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9hyrx724/).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from the fact that you're using an `Array` of numbers for your data, while in Mike Bostock's example he was using an `Array` of `Object`s (for example, `var data = [{value: 30}, ...]`). Thus you need to change all cases of `d.value` to `d` in your code, since your data is not longer an `Object` but just a number.

```
bar.append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d); }) // <---- delete .value
    .attr("width", barWidth - 1)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d); }); // <---- delete .value

bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d) + 3; }) // <---- delete .value
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .text(function(d) { return d; }); // <---- delete .value
```

Making these changes produces the following bar chart:

[image: bar chart]